# How to generate Client Secret in OAuth2 Authentication using Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-security-oauth2

I am working on creating api for OAuth2 using Spring for my application but there is nothing written in the specification (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) nor in Spring OAuth2 Documentation about how to generate client secret.

Do anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring uses [PasswordEncoder](http://org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder) for decoding/encoding clients secrets. See the [JdbcClientDetailsService](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/4fd855600e1ec9462cbae589e7c77c8a41cc3d97/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/JdbcClientDetailsService.java) (if you're planning to store client details in DB).

So when configuring beans for Spring OAuth2 you typically provide an instance of **PasswordEncoder** for the **ClientDetailsService**.

Typical case is to use the [BCryptPasswordEncoder](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html). So before putting encoded **client secret** into database column you can write a sample program to generate it:

```
String password = "testPassword";
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
```

Comment: Can you add any example of storing client id and client secret in database?