# In Spring Security OAuth, how do you use a passwordEncoder for client secrets?

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to BCrypt the client secrets I'm storing in the database when using Spring Security Oauth2. I can see that `JdbcClientDetailsService` has a `setPasswordEncoder` method (as [mentioned in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058665/how-to-generate-client-secret-in-oauth2-authentication-using-spring)). However, the `ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer` on `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` does not show any obvious way of setting the password encoder. Does anyone know how to do this? I've included the authorization server configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;
    @Autowired
    private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;
    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenApprovalStore tokenApprovalStore() {
        TokenApprovalStore tokenApprovalStore = new TokenApprovalStore();
        tokenApprovalStore.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return tokenApprovalStore;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler() {
        LocalUserApprovalHandler handler = new LocalUserApprovalHandler();
        handler.setApprovalStore(tokenApprovalStore());
        handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));
        handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        handler.setUseApprovalStore(true);
        return handler;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore)
                .userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) {
        oauthServer.realm("abcdefgh/client");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of release 2.0.5, `passwordEncoder(...)` methods are now available on both `ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer` and `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer`, which are made available when extending `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter`. Use the same `PasswordEncoder` implementation on both and the configuration is relatively easy.

Comment: Do you have a code example of how to use it with ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer?

Comment: In regards to `ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer`, the `passwordEncoder(...)` method is actually on the `JdbcClientDetailsServiceBuilder` returned from the jdbc(...) method

Comment: An example of this: https://github.com/jogiwithjosh/Spring-Boot-OAuth2/blob/master/authorization/src/main/java/com/nerve24/OAuth2AuthorizationConfig.java

Answer (score 1):

`ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer` doesn't really need to encode passwords if they are already in the database. If you use a backend store you should just inject it into the configurer, and deal with creating the data in the back end as a separate problem.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand the responsibilities, but I'm not talking about creating the bcrypted secrets, I'm talking about matching them later. The client secrets are already BCrypted in the DB. However, when the client presents its secret (HTTP Basic over SSL, but not bcrypted - as is correct), the configured client details service would need a reference to the appropriate PasswordEncoder to do a match(...). Otherwise, what part does this?

Comment: Isn't that why the `JdbcClientDetails` has that setter for the password encoder? You create them and bind them together and then plug them into the OAuth2 configurer. I'm not looking at the code right now, but I'm pretty sure that's all there is to it (and I know I've seen people using the encoder).

Comment: I can't find any *working* examples of people using the encoder with OAuth2, so if you've got one I'd love to see it. I've tried creating the JdbcClientDetailsService and setting the PasswordEncoder on it, but whenever I then try to push it into the Builder, it doesn't work. I either get null assertions or it silently just uses the default encoder so the unbcrypted secrets being passed in by clients don't work. I also don't have access to my code right now, but from what I've included where would you put the encoder, details service and configurer together?